# how to hide work sheet in epplus in C#?

Tags: c#, epplus

I found nothing in web about hiding worksheet in epplus. How can I hide `ddworksheet`?

```
ExcelWorksheet ddworksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DropDownList");
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can using the `Hidden` property of the worksheet:

```
ExcelWorksheet ddworksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DropDownList");
ddworksheet.Hidden = OfficeOpenXml.eWorkSheetHidden.Hidden;
```

Comment: @user3035588 no problem. Just remember to mark the question as answered to close it. And welcome to stack overflow.

Comment: The given solution didn't work for me, but this did:`ddworksheet.Hidden = OfficeOpenXml.eWorkSheetHidden.VeryHidden;`

Answer (score 4):

I know this thread is old but for everyones help
Hidden will not work if the sheet that you want to be hidden is active, and so use ws.select to select some other sheet before you save. 
Otherwise hidden will have no impact and only VeryHidden will work.